Porting Prop Logic proves from lean3 to lean4
How we could port this code to lean4 and where I could find the documentation about on lean3 to lean4 porting?
theorem my_theorem : P ∧ Q → Q ∧ P :=
assume h : P ∧ Q,
have P, from and.left h,
have Q, from and.right h,
show Q ∧ P, from and.intro ‹Q› ‹P›

end


It's a little unclear whether you are asking about reintegrating Lean3 syntax into Lean4 or just rewriting the given code snippet in Lean4 syntax. I'll assume the latter.
Firstly assume has been replaced by intro in Lean4. Additionally, end now is only used to terminate namespaces. The done tactic has effectively replaced end in Lean 4 but is optional and can instead be substituted by whitespace. If you are interested in learning Lean4 theorem syntax, I recommend you check out Theorem Proving in Lean4 and Lean Game Server. Also check out the Lean Zulip Chat which is more active
Here is the Lean4 equivalent code (note that instead of begin ... end, we use by to start the tactics proof method:
theorem my_theorem : P ∧ Q → Q ∧ P := by
  intro h                     --   h : P ∧ Q
  have hp := And.left h       --  hp : P
  have hq := And.right h      --  hq : Q
  have qΛp := And.intro q p   -- qΛp : Q ∧ P
  exact qΛp                   -- closes the goal

Without tactics, it would look like this:
theorem my_theorem2 : P ∧ Q → Q ∧ P :=
  fun h : P ∧ Q => 
    let hp := And.left h             -- hp : P := h.left
    let hq := And.right h            -- hq : Q := h.right
    show Q ∧ P from And.intro hq hp

Unfortunately, there is no comprehensive Lean3 to Lean4 manual to my knowledge so making the conversion will take some time. There's this post which can guide you further.

Also if you instead meant the former interpretation, you will need some knowledge in Lean Metaprogramming which I'm currently not qualified enough to provide a detailed answer.
